# Is there a simplification of this sum of quadratic sums?

Tags: summation

I have $a(1+2+3+...+N)^2+a(2+3+...+N)^2+a(3+..+N)^2+...+aN^2$, essentially a sum of quadratic terms holding an integer summation that get consecutively smaller  Within each term the summation up to N elements (which could also go to infinity if that makes life easier). Some experimentation lead me to believe that this converge to something when divided by $N^{-5}$, but don't take my word for it. Any simplification here possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica gives the following result:
$$ \frac{1}{30} a \; n (n+1) (2 n+1) (2n^2+2n+1) $$
Hopefully I'm interpreting your summation correctly.

It seems to give the correct result if for example letting $N=3$ for your summation gives:
$$ a((1+2+3)^2+(2+3)^2+(3)^2))=70a $$
which is what the formula above gives.

**EDIT:**

This is a rather messy prove but it does seem to work and is relatively straightforward.

Looking at it a bit more you could get the result above by writing you summation as:
$$ a \sum _{j=1}^n \left(\sum _{i=j}^n i\right){}^2 $$
then writing the inner sum from $i=j$ to $i=n$ as:
$$ \frac{1}{2} (n-j+1) (j+n) \;\; \text{ which after substituting gives } \;\;a \sum _{j=1}^n[\frac{1}{2} (n-j+1) (j+n)]^2 $$
$$= \frac{a}{4} \sum _{j=1}^n[(n-j+1) (j+n)]^2 $$
If you then expand $[(n-j+1) (j+n)]^2 $ and then collect the terms of $j$ together since that is the index of the outer most summation. Which gives a rather messy result:
$$j^4-2 j^3+j^2 (-2 n^2-2 n+1)+j (2 n^2+2 n)+n^4+2 n^3+n^2$$
But then all you need to know are the summations the powers up to $4$. Since we can then replace the above expression for $ \left(\sum _{i=j}^n i\right){}^2 $ in the outer summation again (which is indexed from $j=1$ to $n$) gives.
$$\sum _{j=1}^n[j^4]-2 \sum _{j=1}^n[j^3]+ \left(-2 n^2-2 n+1\right)\sum _{j=1}^n[j^2]+ \left(2 n^2+2 n\right)\sum _{j=1}^n[j]+ (n^4+2 n^3+n^2)\sum _{j=1}^n[1]$$

Which after substituting in the known formula's for the sums of $j$, $j^2$, $j^3$ and $ j^4$ from to 1 to $n$ and multiplying by $a/4$ gives the final result $$\frac{1}{30} a\; n (n+1) (2 n+1) (2n^2+2n+1)$$

It's definitely not a pretty proof but it works and is quite straightforward, just a bit messy!

Comment: That's definitely right and is what I get as convergence in the n^5 case as the summation converges to around 4/30. But I am yet up to read through the other answers to see how to obtained the closed form solution here...

Comment: @Majte It certainly isn't a clean and elegant proof but it seems to work, just a bit of messy algebra!

Comment: I was hoping for something easier.. but that seems to be it. I give it a night's sleep though. The last step to the final formula seems tedious with all the summations, did you use here mathematica too?

Comment: @Majte Indeed I did, I would not like to do all that simplification. Though this time it was only because I didn't want to do all that algebra whereas in the first place I had no idea whether such a closed form existed; now we just have to find the most elegant way to show how to derive the closed form expression - which is certainly not mine, it's more a brute-force approach!

Comment: @Majte I've simplified the algebra a little bit, I'm still convinced there's a nice elegant way to do this... to make things worse the closed form formula looks very similar to the sum of $i^4$ which is: $ \frac{1}{30} n (n+1) (2 n+1) \left(3 n^2+3 n-1\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the $a$ for now.

Then, the $n$th term is, \begin{align}a_n&=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=n}^{N} i\right)^2
\\&=\left(\dfrac12N(N+1)-\dfrac12n(n-1)\right)^2
\\&=\dfrac14(N^2(N+1)^2+n^2(n-1)^2-2Nn(N+1)(n-1)).\end{align}

So, \begin{align}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N a_n
&=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^N N^2(N+1)^2+\frac14\sum_{n=1}^N n^2(n-1)^2-\frac14\sum_{n=1}^N 2Nn(N+1)(n-1)
\\&=\frac14N^3(N+1)^2+\frac14\sum_{n=1}^N n^2(n-1)^2-\frac12N(N+1)\sum_{n=1}^N n(n-1).\end{align}

Provided you know the closed-forms of $\sum_{n=1}^N n^k$ for $k=1,2,3,4$, you should be good!

---

If you can guess that the answer will be a degree $5$ polynomial (and it's not hard since each term is a degree $4$ polynomial), then another approach would be to first guess the closed-form to be $aN^5+bN^4+cN^3+dN^2+eN$.

Then for $N=1$, it should equal $1$.

So, we get $a+b+c+d+e=1$.

Similarly, for $N=2$, it should equal $13$ and thus, $32a+16b+8c+4d+2e=13$.

After getting $5$ (nasty) linear equations, you can solve them to obtain your answer.

Admittedly, this is yet another cumbersome approach but I thought I'd mention this since as you've already mentioned in your question, you already know that the closed-form will have degree $5$.

Comment: What about the square on each term?

Comment: @AlexBecker Maybe I should start reading questions more carefully! Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I do it all the time.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $1/2$ factor in the $a_n$, since $\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$?

Comment: @AlexBecker And I should start writing answers more carefully. Appreciate that.

Comment: I had it that far too in my notes but then I got stuck. Jays answer using mathematica shows a closed form is strikingly simple.

Comment: @Majte I've added an alternative approach in case you find it useful.

Comment: That's a really cool up! Two thumbs up..!

Answer (score 1):

Factor $a$ out. Let $1+2+ \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}2 = b$. Then, we have

$b^2+(b-1)^2+ \cdots + (b- n(n-1)/2)^2 = $

$(n-1)b^2-2b(1+ \cdots + n(n-1)) +1^2+2^2+ \cdots + (n(n-1)/2)^2$.

All of these sums have well known closed forms so I will leave the rest to you.